# Serialization of a collection of Placemarks in a KML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, kml

I hope I am not just being brain dead here but I am trying to create my own KML class in .NET and use the .net Serialization to actually generate the XML when exporting.  I am stuck on this one part when it comes to placemarks.  According to Google's API, a KML should have, among other things, the Placemarks at the root of the Document Container.  So, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>text.xml</name>
        <open>1</open>

        <Placemark id="PM1">
            <name>PM1 Full Name</name>
            <description>Full Description...</description>

            <Point id="g0">
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <coordinates>-74.001,40.001,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark id="PM2">
            <name>PM3 Full Name</name>
            <description>Full Description...</description>

            <Point id="g1">
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <coordinates>-74.000,40.000,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Note that Placemarks are at the root of Document and not in another Element called "Placemarks" or something.  So how to do I that in .NET with serialzation.  I created something like this:

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("open")]
    public int Open { set; get; }

    //This will Serialize to a container <Placemarks>...</Placemarks>
    public List<Placemark> Placemarks { set; get; }
}

public class Placemark
{
    public Placemark() { }
    public Placemark(string name, string desc) 
        { 
            Name = name; 
            Description = desc; 
        }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

But it generates that extra element <Placemarks>...</Placemarks>.

Thanks

---

Just to respond to the comments, check this example code here:

http://ideone.com/pNdOOh

so this is what the code outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>Test.xml</name>
  <open>0</open>
  <Placemarks>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Mark0</name>
      <description>What I am...</description>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Mark1</name>
      <description>What I am...</description>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Mark2</name>
      <description>What I am...</description>
    </Placemark>
  </Placemarks>
</Document>
```

Comment: Could you pls post the full serialized output. if you don't want <Placemarks> at all, you should implement IEnumerable and add name/open properties.

Comment: I'd also suggest using Linq-to-Xml, which doesn't try to impose any rules unless you set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `XmlElement` attribute on `Placemarks`

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("open")]
    public int Open { set; get; }

    [XmlElement("Placemark")]
    public List<Placemark> Placemarks { set; get; }
}
```

**EDIT**

and to get a similar xml

- declare a class *kml*

  ```
  [XmlRoot(Namespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")]
  public class kml
  {
       public Document Document;
  }
  ```
- and serialize as

  ```
  XmlSerializerNamespaces ns  = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  ns.Add("","http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
  new XmlSerializer(typeof(kml)).Serialize(stream, kml, ns);
  ```

Comment: Are you kidding me?! THANKS! How on earth is it that simple! :)  But seriously, I dont quite get why that works.  Shouldnt it do something like <Placemark><Placemark>...</Placemark></Placemar>?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) which will create the C# class from the [KML Schema](https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml21.xsd).